# Running SQLite inside an Azure Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: azure, sqlite, kubernetes

I am evaluating if it makes sense and is even possible to use an SQLite database inside a Kubernetes cluster that runs on Azure.

I have little to no experience with Kubernetes and Azure. I have some experience with Docker and I imagine running an SQLite database would be as simple as defining a volume that contains the database and has other services on the cluster using it.

Is that considered bad practice since I mostly see Postgres being used in such environments, or am I overthinking it?

I imagine an SQLite database would be useful since users wouldn't have to pay for another Postgres instance and the data being stored is not critical (mostly logs). I just don't know if this is right in a cloud environment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me wrong design. You will have many issues with sqlite, also how will it scale?  The main idea of kubernetes is ability to scale with sqlite you could do it but you will spend lots of time on making it work..

I would recommend you to use [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) service. When it comes to logs its not only storing it also how do you query that. And using app insight for years i think it worth paying for it. If cost is a big deal you can have a look into [sampling](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/sampling-in-application-insights/)